# How to rearrange items in list accordingly to a given pattern?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, java-8, spring-data

I have list of ids, like this: `5, 3, 2, 4, 1` , then i query items from DB with that ids. But they coming from DB usually sorted by id, i mean `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`. I need to rearrange them to be in the same order as they ids list. How can i achieve that?

EDIT: A clarification since many people seem confused about this question. A list of IDs is used to query the database, for example like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE id in (5, 3, 2, 4, 1)
```

The resulting list of Foo objects is not ordered in the same way as the list of IDs. The question is how to obtain a list of Foo objects with the same order as the initial list of IDs.

Comment: read your question 5 times still did not understand your problem

Comment: Don't use a `ORDER BY`? Show us what you have tried.

Comment: If you do a select in the DB for ID 5, the DB returns the data for ID 5. Are you requesting data for different ID's at once?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote, this is a great question! The only thing lacking is a code example of what you've tried yourself.

Comment: Due to the tags chosen for the question, it is unclear, whether you want a way to let the database return the rows in order or whether you want to reorder the list afterwards. In the latter case, all these database specific tags are obsolete and misleading.

Comment: BTW, what version of the postgresql?

Comment: I think OP is hoping for a database solution but so far all the answers have provided solutions in code.

Comment: I searching for any solutions, doesn't matter database or code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to re-order the result of the query in code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> ids = Arrays.asList(5, 3, 2, 4, 1, 6);
    List<Foo> results = Arrays.asList(new Foo(1), new Foo(8), new Foo(2), new Foo(4), new Foo(5), new Foo(7));

    System.out.println("sortResults1: " + sortResults1(ids, results));
    System.out.println("sortResults2: " + sortResults2(ids, results));
}

private static List<Foo> sortResults1(List<Integer> ids, List<Foo> results) {
    Foo[] sortedResultsArray = new Foo[ids.size()];
    for (Foo result : results) {
        // look up the required position of this result's id 
        int pos = ids.indexOf(result.getId());
        if (pos >= 0) {
            sortedResultsArray[pos] = result;
        }
    }
    List<Foo> sortedResults = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(sortedResultsArray));
    sortedResults.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
    return sortedResults;
}

private static List<Foo> sortResults2(List<Integer> ids, List<Foo> results) {
    Collections.sort(results, Comparator.comparingInt(item -> ids.indexOf(item.getId())));
    return results;
}
```

The first solution omits any results with an ID that does not occur in the list of ids.

The second solution with the comparator puts any results with unknown IDs at the front of the result list.

Output:

> ```
> sortResults1: [Foo 5, Foo 2, Foo 4, Foo 1]
> sortResults2[Foo 8, Foo 7, Foo 5, Foo 2, Foo 4, Foo 1]
> ```

Note: Found a similar question here: [Sort an (Array)List with a specific order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566921/sort-an-arraylist-with-a-specific-order)
It has a reasonable answer with a TreeMap.

Comment: You can’t create a `list` from an `int[]` array using `Arrays.asList`, but the manual array creation is obsolete anyway, just use `List<Integer> ids = Arrays.asList(5, 3, 2, 4, 1);`. By the way, you can remove all `null` elements using either, `sortedResults.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));`  or `sortedResults.removeIf(Objects::isNull);`

Comment: The unnecessity of array creation applies to the other `asList` call as well: `results = Arrays.asList(new Foo(1), new Foo(8), …`. Further, you can express the conversion of the array to a list without `null` as Stream operation: `return Arrays.stream(sortedResultsArray) .filter(Objects::nonNull) .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: I stay away from streams, especially in code which is meant to be understood by others ;-) Thanks for the pointers again.

Answer (score 2):

Using pure PostgreSQL,

Version >= 9.5:

```
select * from foo where id = any(array[5,3,2,4,1])
order by array_position(array[5,3,2,4,1], id);
```

Version >= 9.4:

```
with lst(i,n) as (select * from unnest(array[5,3,2,4,1]) with ordinality)
select foo.* from foo join lst on (foo.id = lst.i)
order by lst.n
```

Version >= 8.4:

```
with lst(i,n) as (select *, row_number() over () from unnest(array[5,3,2,4,1]))
select foo.* from foo join lst on (foo.id = lst.i)
order by lst.n
```

Comment: @AdriaanKoster It's depending on where the business logic is. If the main query is autogenerated by Java code for example then the Java solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to sort your list `5, 3, 2, 4, 1`, then you can use

```
Collections.sort(List);
```

If you want to sort a list depending on other list then you should use a comparator, for example

```
Collections.sort(secondList, new Comparator<Item>() {
public int compare(Item left, Item right) {
    return Integer.compare(firstList.indexOf(left.getId(), firstList.indexOf(right.getId());
}
});
```

Note :- This comparator is not very efficient, you should use a hashmap to store the indexes.

Comment: Nice idea with the comparator. But firstList contains the ID's, right? If so, then you should compare `firstList,indexof(left.getId()), firstList,indexOf(right.getId())`

Comment: Yeah, but I just gave an example as the question was not very clear. Anyways I will edit my answer.

Comment: Since this is a Java 8 question, you can implement the comparator as `Comparator.comparingInt(item -> firstList.indexOf(item.getId()))`. For five elements, there is no reason to worry about the performance, a hashmap wouldn’t be faster in that case.

Comment: Sorry my mistake I didn't see the `java8` tag and i just warned him if there are more elements.