# Select objects from table where ids in set and sort result the same way as those ids are sorted

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's assume I have a table **table_data** with *serial* **id** and *text* **name**.

```
select * from table_data where id in (3, 1, 5, 6, 2);
```

Result

*id* | *name*

6 | name6

5 | name5

1 | name1

3 | name3

2 | name2

---

But I wanted the result to be sorted as these ids.

*id* | *name*

3 | name3

1 | name1

5 | name5

6 | name6

2 | name2

These ids can be anything, they are retrieved dynamically before this query.
I would appreciate your help and advice.

Comment: Why do I wanna do this? I use Java EE Criteria API to retrieve objects from the database sorted by custom criteria (user can choose how to sort the result). As the criteria uses joins to other tables, I retrieve ids of matching objects. Then by those ids I want to select objects and run some other quiries, that's why I want those objects to be sorted as ids.

Comment: Already was answered but I fail to find this. For the PostgreSQL 9.5 the simplest way is `select * from table_data where id = any(array[3, 1, 5, 6, 2]) order by array_position(array[3, 1, 5, 6, 2], id);`

Comment: [How to rearrange items in list accordingly to a given pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37833089/593144)

Answer (score 0):

Should work with a CASE in the order by:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_data
ORDER BY case id when 3 then 1
                 when 1 then 2
                 when 5 then 3
                 when 6 then 4
                 when 2 then 5
         end
```

Comment: Not really, in my example I have hardcoded ids. In real, ids are dynamic. They could be any ids. I want to get existing objects and sorted as ids.

Comment: Put the Ids in a temp table and use for each loop

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE table_data (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY , ztext text);
INSERT INTO table_data(id, ztext) VALUES
 (1, 'One'), (2, 'Two'), (3, 'Three'), (4, 'Four'), (5, 'Five'), (6, 'Six');

WITH vals(val) AS (
        VALUES (3), ( 1), ( 5), ( 6), ( 2)
        )
,  list(id,rnk) AS (
        SELECT val
        , row_number() OVER () AS rnk
        FROM vals
        )
SELECT t.id,t.ztext
FROM table_data t
JOIN list l ON l.id = t.id
ORDER BY l.rnk
        ;
```

Note: this relies on the ordering of items within a `VALUES()` set, which is probably not guaranteed. A better solution would be to use a set of pairs.

Comment: Again, the sort in my eample was hardcoded, and so your answer is.
What if these ids can be anything? And I want to preserve the order?

Comment: Maybe because my answer was an answer to your question? (no they are not hardcoded) If the ids are retrieved and/or composed by your program, you could just as well add a ranking field and order on that.

Comment: OK, but it's complicated. Currently, I'm going much easier way: I make an additional request to the database. It is not related to this question.